# Internal application string encode

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a unusual question to solve. How to prevent from reading application strings with hexedit/disasm? Is it possible to write some string-proxy class? I don't want to crypt it hard, just protect from simple replace.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you worried about people replacing your strings?

Comment: Why do you think your question unusual?

Comment: I have great idea how to do this without having mess strings in code. Macros are the anserw i think. Unfortunately I don't know how to write advanced macros. Is it even possible to do macro function with loop that replace string indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said anything about your build system, but I would suggest the following:

First, write a file (`strings.list`?) which contains pairs, `(STRING_NAME, STRING_CONTENTS)`. Any syntax, but make it easy to parse. Maybe just Python code?

Next, write a script that reads this file and generates C++ headers. Suppose your "encryption" scheme was to write the strings out deinterleaved, so all the odd character positions got stored in one place and all the evens in another. Then your script might contain something like

```
names = []
for line in file:
    (name, str) = eval(line)
    odds = calculate_odd_chars(str)
    evens = calculate_even_chars(str)
    print('const char {}_ODDS[] = {!r};'.format(name, odds))
    print('const char {}_EVENS[] = {!r};'.format(name, evens))
    print('char {}[] = "{}";'.format(name, '\\0' * (len(odds) + len(evens)));
    names.append(name)
```

Keep track of the names then, at the end of your script, generate tables that looks something like this:

```
size_t num_mangled_strings = 10;
const char * mangled_pieces [] = { NAME0_ODDS, NAME0_EVENS, /* ... */ };
const char * unmangled_strings [] = { NAME0, /* ... */ };
```

These can all end up in some header (`app_strings.h`?) and you'll want to plumb that into your build system so it gets regenerated when you edit `strings.list`. You've now got enough information at runtime to rebuild everything.

Write some C or C++ code that runs at the start of your program. This should iterate over `mangled_pieces` (in twos) and `unmangled_strings` and "decrypt" your data. Note that I made sure the target buffers were big enough by filling them with \0 characters in the initialisers above. Using \0 should hopefully ensure this ends up in bss rather than initialised data. If space is tight, you could do something fancier with unions maybe (because, of course, the source and target data are the same size).

Once that code has run, you can just pass one of the string names wherever you were using a string constant. At runtime, this will point to the right data, but the application binary will have it mangled in some way.

Note that compilers might moan if you use this trick for `printf` format strings because they just see you passing some random character buffer as a `printf` format: always a dubious thing to do... But if you're writing C++, this shouldn't matter as I guess you're using iostreams.

Hope this gives you some ideas: I wouldn't go overboard on making this complicated though...

Comment: This is excellent idea and with cmake for example is easy to achive. I'm currently using visual studio and there i can call pre-build scripts too. Your response is very helpfull for me. Thanks again.